# Subir archivo en mysql con php

Tags: php, html, mysql, linux, phpmyadmin

Buen dia, espero me puedan ayudar, estoy realizando un sistema en el cual un alumno pueda subir archivos jpg/jpeg y/o pdf, me estoy guiando con algunos ejemplos de la documentacion de php pero aun no logro hacer que funcione, mi problema es que estoy usando los fopen, fread (me gustaria que me dieran su propia opinion a cerca de esto, si es recomendable subir el archivo a la base de dato o que puedo hacer) y no me guarda los datos del archivo, he seguido algunos tutoriales pero aun asi sigo con ese problema, les adjunto mi php y el tipo de dato que estoy usando en mysql es mediumblob

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilos.css">
 <title>Guardar FOLIO</title>
</head>
<body>
 
</body>
</html>
<?php
NuevoFormulario($_POST['nombre'], $_POST['apellidos'], $_POST['numcontrol'], $_POST['carrera']
,$_POST['email'],$_POST['asunto'], $_POST['descripcion'], $_FILES["archivo"]["name"], $_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"], $_FILES["archivo"]["size"]);

function NuevoFormulario($nombre,$apellidos,$numcontrol,$carrera,$email,$asunto,$descripcion,$archivo)

{

   include 'conexion.php';
date_default_timezone_set("America/Mexico_City");

         $caracteres = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
           $elegir_caracter=substr(str_shuffle($caracteres),0,2);

         
         $fecha = date("Y-m-d-h-i");
         $fechatot= date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
         $tickets= $elegir_caracter.'-'.$fecha;
         
         if (!$_POST['numcontrol']){
           $numcontrol=null;
         }

         $nombre_archivo = $_FILES["archivo"]["name"];

         $archivo = $_FILES["archivo"]["tmp_name"];

         $tamaño_archivo = $_FILES["archivo"]["size"];

         $tipo_archivo = strtolower(pathinfo($nombre_archivo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
         
         $carpeta_destino = '/home/mario/pruebas/';
         
         move_uploaded_file($archivo, $carpeta_destino.$nombre_archivo);

         if($tipo_archivo == "jpg" || $tipo_archivo=="jpeg" || $tipo_archivo=="pdf" || empty($nombre_archivo)) {
           
           
        $archivo_obejetivo = fopen($carpeta_destino.$nombre_archivo,"r");
        
        $contenido = fread($archivo_obejetivo, $tamaño_archivo);

        $contenido = addslashes($contenido);

        fclose($archivo_obejetivo);

       $sentencia= "INSERT INTO `administrador` (`tickets`, `nombre`, `apellidos`, `numcontrol`, `carrera`, `email`, `asunto`, `descripcion`, `archivo`,`estado`,
       `fecha`,`enviado`)
       VALUES ('".$tickets."','".$nombre."','".$apellidos."','".$numcontrol."','".$carrera."','".$email."',
           '".$asunto."','".$descripcion."', '".$contenido."', 'Pendiente', '".$fechatot."', 'No')";
       
           $conexion->query($sentencia) or die ("Error al enviar los datos".mysqli_error($conexion));

           echo '<h4 class="text-center">Envio exitoso!</h4>
                 <p class="text-center">Se a enviado con exito '.$_POST['nombre'].'<br>TU TICKET es: <strong>'.$tickets.'</strong><br>Favor de guardar tu <strong>TICKET</strong> 
                 para tener mas información</br>
                 </p><a href="../index.html"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                 <span aria-hidden="true">Regresar</span></button></a>';
       }
       else{
         echo '<h4><strong>Hubo un error</strong></h4>
          El archivo no es valido, Favor de revisar tu archivo<br /> 
          Te recordamos que solo se admiten archivos jpg/jpeg y pdf
          no mayores de 16 Mb<br />
          <a href="../index.html"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">Regresar</span></button></a>';
         }
       
         

       // $id_tickets = $conexion->tickets;
       // if ($_FILES["archivo"]["error"]>0) {
       //   echo '<h4><strong>Hubo un error</strong></h4><br />
       //   El archivo no es valido, Favor de revisar tu archivo<br /> 
       //   Te recordamos que solo se admiten archivos jpg/jpeg y pdf
       //   no mayores de 16 Mb';
       // }
       // else {
       //   $archivos_permitidos = ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "application/pdf"];
       //   $limite_del_tamallo_archivo_kb = 16383.99902;
       //   if (in_array($_FILES["archivo"]["type"], $archivos_permitidos) && $_FILES["archivo"]["size"]<= $limite_del_tamallo_archivo_kb * 1024) {
       //     # code...
       //   }else {
       //     echo '<h4><strong>Hubo un error</strong></h4><br />
       //   El archivo no es valido, Favor de revisar tu archivo<br /> 
       //   Te recordamos que solo se admiten archivos jpg/jpeg y pdf
       //   no mayores de 16 Mb';
       //   }
       // }

       


       }
?>
```

Debo de adjuntar que en el **move_upload_file(....)** no me lo guarda en la carpeta que tengo, segun yo de ahi parte mi error pero se que ustedes podran ayudarme y espero que me puedan dar sus consejos para tener un codigo mas limpio, apenas estoy iniciando en el mundo de la programacio. sin mas que decir que tengan un buen dia, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La carpeta `/home/mario/pruebas/` debe tener permisos de escritura para el proceso de PHP, puedes verificar antes de guardar usando la siguiente secuencia:

```
if (!is_writable($carpeta_destino)) {
   echo "Mensaje de error "; // No se puede guardar en la carpeta de destino
   exit;
}
move_uploaded_file($archivo, $carpeta_destino.$nombre_archivo);
```

Si te aparece el mensaje de error debes ajustar los permisos de la carpeta

Puedes probar primero con la opción mas general (todos los permisos)

```
chmod 777 /home/mario/pruebas/
```

Después de esto posiblemente se pueda escribir, pero no puedes dejar el permiso así que es muy abierto. Si no permite guardar con esto, el problema es distinto.

Luego puedes ajustar el propietario y restringir el permiso

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /home/mario/pruebas/
chmod -R 775 /home/mario/pruebas/
```

Suponiendo que es un servidor apache ejecutando PHP el usuario típicamente es `www-data` (puede ser otro, debes verificar que usuario es el propietario del proceso php)

Si por alguna razon aun no funciona puede estar dando algun error no visible. Puedes activar los mensajes de error agregando lo siguiente antes del html

```
<?php ini_set("display_errors","on"); error_reporting (E_ALL); ?>
<html lang="en">
```

Y ve que mensajes salen que puedan darte alguna idea de que esta pasando.

Comment: Muchas gracias, al parecer mi error está ahi, ya le di permisos a la carpeta pero aun asi no me deja, la pantalla ahora me la deja en blanco

Comment: Ok a veces peude ser algo que no se ve a simple vista. Agregue info para que puedas ver y revisar si aparecen mensajes de error