# No me visualiza bien una imagen subida desde el html y procesada con js/php/mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, jquery

Tengo un formulario donde hay un input para subir imágenes, una vez acepto mediante js y php creo el insert para guardar los datos en el servidor para posteriormente mostrarlos en otra página. He comprobado que guarda la imagen en el servidor pero al descargarla directamente del servidor tiene un formato que mi página no puede interpretar ya que muestra un icono de error de imagen.

================================================================
EDIT: Con los nuevos cambios me salta este error tanto si elijo foto como si no:

```
Request failed: parsererror
```

HTML:

```
<form name="frmAltaNoticia" id="frmAltaNoticia" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <label>IdNoticia: </label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="A0000"class="form-control" id="txtIdNoticia">
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <label>Fecha: </label>
                    <input type="date" placeholder="Fecha" class="form-control" name="txtFecha">
                </div>          
                
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                    <label>Título: </label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Título"class="form-control" name="txtTitulo">
                </div>                                      
                    <br>
                        <br>
                            <br>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                    <label>Autor: </label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Autor"class="form-control" name="txtAutor">
                </div>  
                <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9">
                    <label>Descripción:</label>
                    <textarea name="txtDescripcion" placeholder="Descripción" class="form-control" name="txtDescripcion"></textarea>
                </div>
                
                <br>
                <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
                    <label>Imagen: </label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="txtImagen">
                </div>  
                
            <br>
                <br>
                    <br>
                         <br>
                        
                <div class="col-md-3">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="invalidCheck" required>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck">Aceptas los términos</label>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">Debes aceptar los términos y condiciones</div>
                </div>
                    <br>
                         <br>
                         <br>
                         <br>
                <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg"  onclick="ValidarNoticia()" value="Aceptar"></input>
                </div>  
            </form>
```

PHP:

```
        <?php

// Configuración BASE DE DATOS MYSQL
$servidor  = "localhost";
$basedatos = "BDNoticias";
$usuario   = "root";
$password  = "";

# Obtenemos los datos normales con el estilo que usabas
$oNoticia = json_encode($_POST);


// Creamos la conexión al servidor.
$conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password,$basedatos);
if (!$conexion) { 
    $respuesta["error"]=1;
    #Considera cambiarlo por un mensaje personalizado en producción
    $respuesta["mensaje"]=mysqli_error($conexion);
} else {
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");
    # Pero como dijimos, la imagen está en otra super global
    $mFile = file_get_contents($_FILES['txtImagen']["tmp_name"]);
    $mBlob=base64_encode($mFile);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO noticias (idnoticia, titulo, descripcion, autor, fecha, imagen) VALUES ('$oNoticia->txtIdNoticia','$oNoticia->txtTitulo','$oNoticia->txtDescripcion','$oNoticia->txtAutor','$oNoticia->txtFecha','$mBlob');";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

    if ($resultado){
        $respuesta["error"] = 0;
        $respuesta["mensaje"] = "Alta realizada"; 
    } else {
        $respuesta["error"] = 1;
        $respuesta["mensaje"] = "Error en el proceso de alta: ".mysqli_error($conexion);
    }
}

echo json_encode($respuesta);
//var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($oNoticia);

mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

JS:

```
function crearNoticia()  
{
    /* Esta línea basta para recoger todo lo que haya en el 
    formulario*/
    var mData = new FormData(document.getElementById("frmAltaNoticia"));
var mAjax = $.ajax({
    url: "../ApartadosPHP/altanoticias.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: mData,
    processData: false,  
    contentType: false,
    dataType: "json"
});

mAjax.done(function( oDatos ) {
    respuestaAltaNoticia(oDatos);
});

mAjax.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
};


function respuestaAltaNoticia(oDatos, sStatus, oXHR) {

if (oDatos.error) 
{
    alert(oDatos.mensaje);
} 
else 
{
    alert(oDatos.mensaje);
    frmAltaNoticia.reset();
}
}
```

var_dump:

```
    index.js:640 string(117) "{"txtIdNoticia":"G7894","txtFecha":"2021-08-05","txtTitulo":"noticia","txtAutor":"pepe","txtDescripcion":"noticiass"}"
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property 'txtIdNoticia' of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectoFinal\ProyectoSenderismo\ApartadosPHP\altanoticias.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property 'txtTitulo' of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectoFinal\ProyectoSenderismo\ApartadosPHP\altanoticias.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property 'txtDescripcion' of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectoFinal\ProyectoSenderismo\ApartadosPHP\altanoticias.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property 'txtAutor' of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectoFinal\ProyectoSenderismo\ApartadosPHP\altanoticias.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property 'txtFecha' of non-object in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\proyectoFinal\ProyectoSenderismo\ApartadosPHP\altanoticias.php</b> on line <b>24</b><br />
{"error":0,"mensaje":"Alta realizada"}
```

Comment: Realmente no estás subiendo la imagen. Primero, la etiqueta formulario debe tener atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"` para poder enviar archivos. Luego, en PHP debes usar `move_uploaded_file()` para mover la imagen de carpeta temporal a su destino final. Por último, al insertar en MySQL también debes incluir la imagen, de preferencia, solo el nombre. Te recomiendo leer [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/391554/subir-archivo-en-mysql-con-php) tal vez te sea útil para comenzar a corregir esos errores.

Comment: @Triby depende... yo subo archivos al mismo tiempo que envió variables con: `contentType: false, processData: false, type: 'POST',`

Comment: lo que no agrega es como hace en php para recibir los archivos...

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso, cierto, no vi que tiene petición AJAX. Eso me pasa por no leer la pregunta completa. xD

Comment: Si me ha dado cuenta que en el insert no esta puesto los campos para la imagen, se ve que hice CONTROL + Z y lo eliminé, paso a editarlo aunque en mi proyecto ya esta así y no funciona. Estoy documentándome pero en un sitios pone que tengo que codificar antes, en otros sitios después, otros que no hace falta... estoy muy liado con esto.

Comment: He añadido el "enctype="multipart/form-data"  pero al poner esto asi: '$oNoticia->$imagenCodificada' para codificar la imagen  no me detecta la variable y no me guarda imagen usando: $imagenCodificada = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name']));

Comment: ¿Por qué con js en lugar hacerlo naturalmente? Se puede, no precisamente con un par líneas de código, pero incluso existiendo librerías que ayudan a eso ¿Por qué tomar el camino de terracería?

Comment: Creo que deberías agregar la imagen a un canvas y después convertirla en Blob para mantener la lógica que estás usando. Acá encontré un ejemplo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42471755/convert-image-into-blob-using-javascript

Comment: Estoy tratando de implementar ese ejemplo pero no hay manera, tengo todo el tiempo el mismo problema @N.N.

Comment: @Sal que librerías podrían ayudarme? podrías ponerme un ejemplo?

Comment: ¿Podrías actualizar el código con los cambios que hiciste? Me acabo de dar cuenta que dentro de `$sql` estás llamando a propiedades de un objeto `$oNoticia->Autor` y tengo entendido que esa función de las comillas dobles sólo sirve con nombres de variables. Si decidiste usar `$_FILES["input_name"]` tendrías que ponerle ese atributo `name` al input en el formulario.

Comment: Igual creo que es mejor almacenar la imagen en algún otro lado, porque sino cada vez que guardes un registro en una variable, va a ocupar en memoria lo que pese la imagen, que va a ser MUCHO más de lo que ocupen el resto de los datos.

Comment: Probé poniendo el atributo al input y nada, es que no me funciona haga lo que haga, no se como ponerlo ya. Yo se que guardándolo en el servidor es un gasto alto de memoria pero quiero aprender a hacerlo por eso lo quiero implementar en mi proyecto. @N.N.

Comment: Otra cosa que no se como manejar es que al aceptar el formulario, lo datos van al .js y éste mediante ajax es el que manda los datos al .php, pero para gestionar la imagen no se si debería mandarle la imagen directamente al .php

Comment: Quizás haya que hacer `Imagen: await frmAltaNoticia.txtImagen.files[0].text()`.

Comment: Tampoco funciona con eso @N.N.

Comment: Puedes simplificar mucho tu código haciendo lo siguiente: 1. Declaras el `form` como multi part; 2. Das una etiqueta `name` a los 'input` cuyos datos quieres enviar (archivos y/o texto); 3. Usas FormData para recoger todo y mandarlo al servidor; 4. En el servidor desglosas el contenido del FormData obteniendo los datos enviados y procesándolos. Revisa por ejemplo [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/426611/29967) donde se explica lo fácil y claro que es trabajar con FormData.

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de dato es `noticias.imagen`?

Comment: ¿A que te refieres? ¿Dónde se encuentra eso? @Sal

Comment: A la columna imagen de la tabla noticias.

Comment: Sigo sin ver la salida que ahora me interesa. Ponlo justo después de crearlo por favor y no hace falta que subas capturas de pantalla, simplemente copia pega TODO el texto sin intentar decirme *esto es esto y esto es lo otro*, viendo el var_dump ya sabré lo que es... No pongas esto al final: `var_dump($oNoticia);` sino aquí, en la línea siguiente a donde lo declaras: `$oNoticia = json_encode($_POST); echo "ESTE ES EL VAR_DUMP de $oNiticia:\n"; var_dump($oNoticia);` Cuando estás depurando código, **depura las variables justo en la línea siguiente a su declaración**.

Comment: Hecho, pongo var_dump porque si no me lo mezcla con el código  de arriba, es para que haya separación. @A. Cedano

Comment: @Sal el tipo de dato es imagen, un input type="file".

Comment: OK. Para crear el objeto tendría que ser así:  `$oNoticia = json_decode(json_encode($_POST));`

Comment: Ahora si me guarda los datos en el servidor pero la imagen creo que no la sube correctamente porque no la muestra. @A. cedano

Comment: No la muestra donde ¿? ¿Revisaste la base de datos?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128539/discussion-between-a-cedano-and-john-doe).

Comment: Me refiero a la columna imagen de la tabla noticias, de la base de datos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hay varios errores en tu código:

1. Para enviar imágenes debes declarar el formulario con el atributo `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Esto significa literalmente que el formulario tiene **varias partes**, por un lado los datos normales como nombre, apellido, etc, que estarán en la super global del método del formulario (`$_POST`, `$_GET` ...) y por otra parte los archivos, que estarán en la super global `$_FILES`.
2. Los archivos adjuntos no se serializan tan fácilmente *a mano*, como los otros datos. Para simplificar este proceso lo más simple es usar [la API FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects), en el apartado [*Enviando archivos usando objetos FormData*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#enviando_archivos_usando_objetos_formdata) podrás ver la facilidad con que puedes enviar formularios multi-part al servidor desde Javascript.
3. Para poder usar FormData sin demasiadas complicaciones, conviene dar un atributo `name` a todos los elementos en los que quieres poner información.
4. En el servidor, algo como esto `$datosJSON = $_POST["datos"];` no recogería toda la información que viaja en un formulario multi-part. Como ya se dijo en (1) los archivos se encuentran en la super global `$_FILES`.
5. Si la petición Ajax espera en respuesta un JSON, no puedes en ningún caso emitir esto: `die(mysqli_error($conexion)`, en caso de error no habrá un JSON, sino una cadena, debes controlar eso agregando una clave de error en `$respuesta`.
6. Esto `mysqli_query($conexion,"utf8")` no tiene ningún sentido en tu código. El charset lo estableciste con `mysqli_set_charset()`.

Podemos aplicar lo dicho en tu código del siguiente modo:

### HTML

Damos un atributo `name` a los inputs, así FormData serializará automáticamente todos los inputs que tengan datos escritos sin tener que hacerlo a mano. Para simplificar cambiaremos los atributos `id` por `name`.

```
<form name="frmAltaNoticia" id="frmAltaNoticia" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                <label>IdNoticia: </label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="A0000"class="form-control" name="txtIdNoticia">
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                <label>Fecha: </label>
                <input type="date" placeholder="Fecha" class="form-control" name="txtFecha">
            </div>          
            
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <label>Título: </label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Título"class="form-control" name="txtTitulo">
            </div>                                      
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                <label>Autor: </label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Autor"class="form-control" name="txtAutor">
            </div>  
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-9 col-md-9">
                <label>Descripción:</label>
                <textarea name="txtDescripcion" placeholder="Descripción" class="form-control" id="txtDescripcion"></textarea>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-5 col-md-5">
                <label>Imagen: </label>
                <input type="file" class="form-control" name="txtImagen">
            </div>  
                    
            <div class="col-md-3">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" name="invalidCheck" required>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="invalidCheck">Aceptar los términos</label>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">Debes aceptar los términos y condiciones</div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
            <input type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg"  id="btnAceptarNoticia" onclick="ValidarNoticia()" value="Aceptar"></input>
            </div>  
        </form>
```

### Javascript

Hay varias modificaciones aquí. En lugar del método abreviado `$.post`, usaremos `$.ajax`, que nos permite con mayor claridad setear otros parámetros que son necesarios para FormData. Además nos permite manejar un bloque `done` y otro `fail` siempre recomendable para errores. De hecho, los parámetros que pasabas `respuestaAltaNoticia()` no eran correctos. Una cosa son los errores propios de la respuesta y otra los errores propios de la petición en sí misma que deben ser manejados siempre en `fail`.

```
function crearNoticia()  {
    /* Esta línea basta para recoger todo lo que haya en el formulario*/
    var mData = new FormData(document.getElementById("frmAltaNoticia"));
    var mAjax = $.ajax({
        url: "../ApartadosPHP/altanoticias.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: mData,
        processData: false,  
        contentType: false,
        dataType: "json"
    });

    mAjax.done(function( oDatos ) {
        respuestaAltaNoticia(oDatos);
    });

    mAjax.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
}

function respuestaAltaNoticia(oDatos) {

    if (oDatos.error) 
    {
        alert(oDatos.mensaje);
    } 
    else 
    {
        alert(oDatos.mensaje);
        frmAltaNoticia.reset();
    }
}
```

### PHP

```
# Obtenemos los datos normales con el estilo que usabas
$oNoticia = json_decode($_POST);


// Creamos la conexión al servidor.
$conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password,$basedatos);
if (!$conexion) { 
    $respuesta["error"]=1;
    #Considera cambiarlo por un mensaje personalizado en producción
    $respuesta["mensaje"]=mysqli_error($conexion);
} else {
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion,"utf8");
    # Pero como dijimos, la imagen está en otra super global
    $mFile = file_get_contents($_FILES['txtImagen']["tmp_name"]);
    $mBlob=$conexion->real_escape_string($mFile);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO noticias (idnoticia, titulo, descripcion, autor, fecha, imagen) VALUES ('$oNoticia->txtIdNoticia','$oNoticia->txtTitulo','$oNoticia->txtDescripcion','$oNoticia->txtAutor','$oNoticia->txtFecha','$mBlob');";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

    if ($resultado){
        $respuesta["error"] = 0;
        $respuesta["mensaje"] = "Alta realizada"; 
    } else {
        $respuesta["error"] = 1;
        $respuesta["mensaje"] = "Error en el proceso de alta: ".mysqli_error($conexion);
    }
}

echo json_encode($respuesta);

mysqli_close($conexion);
```

### PD: Advertencia sobre la seguridad

La consulta INSERT que estás implementando aquí es altamente vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Un usuario mal intencionado podría manipular cualquiera de los valores y preparar un código que cause daños irreparables en tu sistema o en tus datos. Considera usar consultas preparadas para neutralizar ese riesgo.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128537/discussion-on-answer-by-a-cedano-no-me-visualiza-bien-una-imagen-subida-desde-e).